# Change display style on div using only CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I'm using haml and scss on a rails website and I have a "learn more" anchor tag. I want to be able to hover over the anchor tag and display a div with a class of ".tb-description" using only CSS(SASS) if possible. How can I change the display style on the div.tb-description?

haml code:

```
.book
  %span.tb-message
    = number_to_currency(tb_array[0], :precision => 0)
    = link_to '#', :class=>"tb-learn-more-link" do
      learn more
.tb-description
  .tb-description-content
    This is text I want to display when the "tb-learn-more-link" anchor tag is hovered over
```

scss code:

```
.tb-learn-more-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: .313em;
}
.tb-description {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 14px 0 0 10px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use javascript here? It'll be fast enough.

Comment: I was hoping to just use CSS because similar hover effects on this site are handled with CSS, thinking the consistency would provide better readability since I'm not the only person working on it. I ended up using javascript anyways.

Comment: I thought so, but the other cases involved elements that had parent/child relationships, so the context isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a pure-CSS-based solution, you cannot achieve this. You have to choose between these two solutions:

1. Keep the actual page layout and implement a solution via javascript, listening to `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events and then applying changes to the hidden `div` accordingly
2. Modify the page layout so that the link you want to hover and the hidden `div` are siblings in the DOM structure. This way you can make use of the `+` CSS operator and hide/unhide the `div` using the `:hover` pseudo-class on the anchor

Sadly CSS is not capable of reverse-traversing the DOM structure, so you will never be able to modify the aspect of `.tb-description` when you hover `.tb-learn-more-link` since they belong to different branches of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the :hover pseudo class in css. http://jsfiddle.net/W6V7r/

```
<a href="#" class="more">More...</a><div class="description">blah blah blah blah</div>

.more {

}
.description {
    display:none;
}
.more:hover+div.description{
    display:block;
}
```

**EDIT** If you can't get to the DIV from the A tag's :hover then you are stuck with a click and using :target pseudo class.

```
<a href="#desc" class="more">More...</a>
<br><hr><br>
<div id="desc" class="description">blah blah blah blah</div>

.more {

}
.description {
    display:none;
}
div.description:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work either. The link and the div are not direct siblings, they live in different sections. The `+` operator will not catch this situation!

Comment: @marzapower - You can't use hover then. You'd either need to use the onmouse[enter/over] javascript event or if you insist on css only you'd have to use anchor hash and make the user click on the "more" link.

Comment: In fact, this is not my question. I suggested to the owner to use Javascript, because IMHO is the only way to solve such a problem given that layout.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I originally tried and for whatever reason it's not working in my code. I think something's wonky in this particular instance; I'm just going to try a javascript solution instead. I'll post an answer if I figure out with this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
.tb-learn-more-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: .313em;
}
.tb-learn-more-link:hover .tb-description {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 14px 0 0 10px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not going to work, since the `.tb-description` is not inside the `.tb-learn-more-link`!

Comment: Misread that! my mistake, thought it was a parent/child relationship, thanks for catching that, @lastcoder's answer has the right idea

Answer (score 0):

**You can use CSS selectors and a pseudo class for this.**

HTML:

```
<div class="tb-description">
    Description
</div>
<div class="tb-description-content">
    Content on hover
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tb-description+.tb-description-content {
    display: none;
}
.tb-description:hover+.tb-description-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: As for @LastCoder's answer, this will not work with his current page layout.

Comment: @marzapower - You are correct.  In the case where we can't infer a relationship between the two elements they have to be explicitly connected.  @LastCoder's edit introducing the pseudo `:target` property will achieve this.

Comment: You cannot achieve the equivalent of a `:hover` with a click! That's just not the same thing. The question is specific on this.